# Vite / Vue.js - Relative Folder / Module Import Aliases

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, alias, vite

Good day!

I'm trying to find out how to create a relative folder alias in Vite.
This problem comes from what I'm trying to do.
Basically divide a Vue.js app structure into sub-apps called modules.

A sample structure will be as follows.
Each modules has `components/`, `layouts/`, `assets/`, etc. folders.

```bash
src/ 
    modules/ 
        dashboard/                  # dashboard module
            components/
            layouts/
            assets/
            views/
        demos/                      # demos module
            components/
            layouts/
            assets/
            views/ 
        blog/                       # blog module 
            components/ 
            layouts/ 
            assets/     
            views/
        discussions/                # forums module  
            components/ 
            layouts/ 
            assets/     
            views/
    registerModules.js              # a file that will register the modules in the modules/folder
...
index.html
vite.config.js
...
```

I picked this kind of structure in the hope that it's easer to add or remove features
in the long run using this way, and also, for organization purposes.

This works. However, I'm left with relatively long imports. For example, when importing
a component in the `blog` module, I have to specify this long line of path:

```js
import '@/modules/blog/components/SomeComponent.vue`
```

This is tedious and might be risky in the future say when I try to rename the `blog` module.

I came up with an idea that I'm currently finding as hard to implement.

The idea is like this. Say I'm in the `blogs` module. I want to have my imports like this instead.

```
module://components/SomeComponent.vue
```

The module should automatically refer to the `@/src/modules/blog` when the script is under `@/modules/blog/`. If the script is in `@/modules/demos`, the `module://` alias should point to `@/modules/demos` accordingly.

The same goes with `dashboard`, `demos`, and `discussions`. Each should have their own `module://`
alias which points to `@/modules/dashboard`, `@/modules/demos`, and `@/modules/discussions`
respectively.

I know how to make normal aliases in `vite.config.js` but how do I implement a more complicated
alias like this?

The idea I have in mind is to capture the filepath of the file that currently imports.
Say `@/modules/blog/components/SomeComponent.vue`. And then, using a function alias, automatically
dissect the filepath to identify what module the script that has the import statement is in.

```
@/modules/blog/components/SomeComponent.vue
          ^ the script is in the `blogs` module
          thus, module:// is @/modules/blog
```

### PSEUDOCODE

`vite.config.js`

```js
  export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
        'module:/': () => {
            const filepath = get_Filepath_Of_Script_That_Is_Importing();            // <--- how to get this???
            const modulePath = get_Path_Of_Module_That_Filepath_Belongs_To(file)   // <--- this is easier
            return modulePath;
        }
    }
})
```

How do I found out the `get_Filename_Of_Script_That_Is_Importing()` above? Is there a way in Vite
to know which file imports using the alias? I will be using the full filepath to find out the module folder.